# Problems creating a popup in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to add an option for a user to select a theme using a popup window. However, when the respective item is clicked in my navigation drawer, no popup is shown. I have the following code which handles navigation drawer item clicks:

```
drawerRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.drawer_recycler);
    drawerRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    drawerRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(

            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getApplicationContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

                    Log.e("STATUS:","User has clicked item: " + String.valueOf(position));

                    switch (position){

                        case 1: //MP1

                            new infoGetter("MP1").execute();
                            break;

                        case 2: //MP2

                            new infoGetter("MP2").execute();
                            break;

                        case 3: //MP3

                            new infoGetter("MP3").execute();
                            break;

                        case 4: //MP4

                            new infoGetter("MP4").execute();
                            break;

                        case 5: //Schedule

                            break;

                        case 6: //Attendance

                            break;

                        case 7: //Theme


                            popupLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.theme);
                            popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupLayout);
                            popupWindow.setContentView(popupLayout);
                            popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);


                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }

                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                }
            })
    );
```

and my theme layout as follows:

> theme_fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="300dp"
android:layout_height="350dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/theme"

android:background="@drawable/rounded_popup"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Select Theme:"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Material Red"
    android:id="@+id/theme_red"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light"
    android:checked="false"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:focusable="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Material Green"
        android:id="@+id/theme_green"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/theme_red"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Material Blue"
        android:id="@+id/theme_blue"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light"
        android:checked="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/theme_green"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:enabled="true" />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Material Violet"
        android:id="@+id/theme_purple"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_material_light"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/theme_blue"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:focusable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So basically, how can I have it so that my popup window is shown and then dismissed after a checkbox is selected?

Comment: Do you need to call [showAtLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)  on the PopupWindow to display it?

Comment: @adelphus yes: popupLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.theme);
                                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupLayout);
                                popupWindow.setContentView(popupLayout);
                                popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER,0,0);